# Change Kotlin Javascript output directory

Tags: kotlin-js

I have just started using Kotlin to produce Javascript, but cannot find a way to change the Javascript output directory.

This is specifically for a nodejs target, and using Gradle with Kotlin script.

There is an example given in the Kotlin docs for a browser target:

```
kotlin.target.browser {
    distribution {
        directory = File("$projectDir/output/")
    }
}
```

but there does not seem to be an equivalent for `kotlin.target.nodejs`

Answer (score 2):

This is now easy (Kotlin 1.40):

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/js-project-setup.html#distribution-target-directory

```
kotlin {
    js {
        browser {
            distribution {
                directory = File("$projectDir/output/")
            }
        }
        binaries.executable()
        // . . .
    }
}
```

Comment: Incredible! I give up and drink coffee, come back 1 hour later and google it again, and here you are! Absolute godsend. I've been scratching my eyes out for a good 4 hours now, and it's a 3-liner.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question btw, it was asking about NodeJS exclusively. Anyway, here is my working solution for _my_ issue, based off this answer - https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2019246. Thanks so much!

Comment: whoops.. I was searching for the browser solution myself and this came up as the first result. Didn't read carefully enough. Your snippet looks like it's also browser unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Yep, my snippet also doesn't answer the question :P. It just solves the same problem you had, from what I can see.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there are no possibilities to do this with NodeJS. I created an issue - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-40416.

Comment: Thank you, I'll monitor that